# Connecting to locally hosted MySQL from terminus in Mac

Tags: mysql

I have MAMP installed in my Applications folder on my Mac, and the project files inside the htdocs folder on MAMP.

If I want to connect to MySQL from the command line, what would I type into the command line?

Note, it says that to connect to MySQL from my scripts I need to use the following, but I'm not sure how it will look from the command line

Host    localhost
Port    8889
User    root
Password    root

EDIT - after running `sudo ps -aef | grep mysqld` in my terminus, I got the following.

```
 501   528     1   0   0:00.02 ??         0:00.02 /bin/sh /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe --port=8889 --socket=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock --lower_case_table_names=0 --pid-file=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.pid --log-error=/Applications/MAMP/logs/mysql_error_log
  501   598   528   0   0:00.77 ??         0:03.72 /Applications/MAMP/Library/libexec/mysqld --basedir=/Applications/MAMP/Library --datadir=/Applications/MAMP/db/mysql --user=mysql --lower_case_table_names=0 --log-error=/Applications/MAMP/logs/mysql_error_log.err --pid-file=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.pid --socket=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock --port=8889
  501  6083  4176   0   0:00.00 ttys000    0:00.00 grep mysqld
```

EDIT
[image: mysql]

working answer
$ mysql --host=127.0.0.1 --port=8889 --user=root -p
Enter password:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mysql --host=127.0.0.1 --port=8889 --user=root -p
```

or

```
mysql --socket=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock --user=root -p
```

The default password for the mysql root account under MAMP is root, so when it prompts for the password, enter "root" (but don't include the quotes).  So, if you want to provide the password right on the main command line, versus prompting for it, do as follows:

```
mysql --socket=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock --user=root --password=root
```

Comment: is that -p  mean password? if so, what password are they asking for?  thanks for your help

Comment: If it was a fresh install, and you didn't specify a root password, you could login as root with no password, as follows:  "mysql --host=127.0.0.1 --user=root", which will use a blank password.  The --host may be optional as well.  If you specified a password, use the "-p" option, and enter the password you configured on install.  I've not used MAMP specifically (I use HomeBrew), so I'm not sure how that installer work.

Comment: if I try --host=127.0.0.1 method, it says I can't connect on that server. If I try --host=localhost etc it says I can't connect through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)

Comment: Are you sure it's running?  Try "telnet 127.0.0.1 3306", if you get gibberish, it's running.  If not, then it's not.  You can also do "sudo ps -aef | grep mysqld"

Comment: MAMP is running, if that's what you mean. when I tried telnet, it said connection refused.  When I ran "sudo ps -aef | grep mysqld" it did a whole bunch of stuff but I'm not sure if I'm in

Comment: I'm not in MySQL after trying "sudo.." because I tried to create a database and it said "-bash: CREATE command not found

Comment: Hrmm...  It sounds as though mysql is not listening on port 3306 (which is the default), or it's not running.  You should see something like the following line from the ps output "0:34.70 /usr/local/mysql/libexec/mysqld --basedir=/usr/local/mysql", can you paste that here?

Comment: mysql is running because I can use it through php my admin. what am I supposed to type in to get this output? "0:34.70 /usr/local/mysql/libexec/mysqld --basedir=/usr/local/mysql

Comment: This will tell you what port mysql is listening on "sudo lsof -i -P | grep mysql"

Comment: To answer your prior question: sudo ps -aef | grep mysqld

Comment: When I put that long string in, it said, "-bash: 0:34.70 /usr/local/mysql/libexec/mysqld --basedir=/usr/local/mysql: No such file or directory

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean for you to paste that into your shell.  I was wanting you to run "sudo ps -aef | grep mysqld" and something like what I pasted above should be the output.

Comment: When I put in "sudo lsof -i -P | grep mysq", it gave me a long string which I will attach in the OP because it's too long for her.

Comment: I ran "sudo ps -aef | grep mysqld"  see OP after EDIT for the output

Comment: I updated my answer.  Your mysql is running on 8889, rather than the default of 3306.

Comment: thank you. we're getting closer, but it says now "ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)"

Comment: Cool.  Now, we need to figure out what user you need to login as.  What user do you use to log into phpmyadmin?

Comment: Are you supplying a password?  If so, then add the "-p" option to the mysql command, and enter that password.

Comment: there's a screen shot in the OP from my phpmyadmin

Comment: i supplied a password and it said, Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (61)

Comment: The default password for root@localhost is "root".  I updated my answer.

Comment: when I tried your other alternative in your answer (with the socket) with a password it said Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES).. note my password was not "YES"

Comment: The "YES" is just saying that yes, you did provide a password.  If you don't provide one at all, it will say (using password: NO).  Did you use the password "root"?

Comment: I just did, "mysql --socket=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock --user=root -p=root" and it said Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: just do -p, not -p=root.   You can provide the password right on the command line, but you must use --password=root.  I'll update my answer again.

Comment: it worked. thank you so much for your patience. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Beware, supplying the password on the command line such as this is insecure, because other users can see it if they do a ps -aef and view the commands executed.  Not a big deal if it's just your local machine.